# Website php How to limit access to files

Tags: php

I have built a website and I have used a lot of include statements in my php script in order to make everything simpler.

So for example I have a index.php file which goes like this:

```
<?php include 'script/uppage.php';?>
<div id='ContentArea' class="container">   
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <?php
            switch($page){
                case 'register':
                    include 'pages/register.php';
                    break;
                case 'fp':
                    include 'pages/forgotpassword.php';
                    break;
                default:
                    include 'pages/main.php';
                    break;
            }?>        
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php include 'script/side_menu.php' ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php include 'script/downpage.php';?>
```

I want to deny access if people are trying to enter for example register.php directly from their browser. So if they would enter www.mywebsite.com/pages/register.php it would show an error.

Are there any general guidelines how to make this for big websites and some basic principles. Any help very appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way is to just keep it out of the public_html, or web root, directory.

Comment: How do I access them?

Comment: They don't need to be in the web directory to be included.  Provide an absolute or relative path to them based on where they are, for instance `../pages/register.php`.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments - you can store this files outside you site folder, i.e. `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and include'em like:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../pages/main.php';
```

Another option is defining some special constant in a top file, e.g.

```
<?php 
define('SOME_CONSTANT', true);  // here, we define a constant
include 'script/uppage.php';?>
```

Then if your included file just check for it, for example in `pages/main.php`:

```
<?php
if (!defined('SOME_CONSTANT') || SOME_CONSTANT !== true) {
    die();
}
// other code
```

Answer (score -3):

So, i use the .htaccess file to do this.

Just add the line `Options All -Indexes` in .htaccess file.

Comment: That's not disallowing access to the file.  It's just getting rid of the directory index.